# Eclipse, CDT C++ analog of java ctrl + alt + o auto import

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am going to write C++ in Eclipse and I found that it's very unusual not to have auto import shortcut like  ctrl + alt + o for Java. Is there such thing for C++ in Eclipse?If yes, how can I tune it?

Comment: Questions usually end with *?*

Comment: In the versions I used (last time over a year ago) that feature was not available. The languages differ and providing that in C++ is much more complex for the editor for many reasons. In the upcoming C++1x standard they might pick the concept of modules back... that would ease the cost of implementing this for IDEs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if Eclipse had this option back when the question was first asked. I now use Eclipse a lot and the way you do this is: **ctrl+ Shift + o**